# Polymer Unit Testing unreliable Platform.flush

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, polymer

I have set up a testing framework for polymer elements and have the following convenience functions for Mocha, the `element` is the polymer element to be tested in an `<iframe>`:

```
this.ctx.set = function(callback) {
  callback.call(this, this.element);
  Platform.flush();
  return this;
};
this.ctx.then = function(callback) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    callback.call(this, this.element);
    this.test.callback();
  }.bind(this), 100);
  return this;
};
```

These are then used like so:

```
(function() {
  'user strict';
  elementSuite('vca-colour-picker', function() {
    test('setting the web value should be reflected in the RGB values', function(done) {
      this.set(function(element) {
        element.web = '#FFCC88';
      }).then(function(element) {
        assert.equal(element.r, 255);
        assert.equal(element.g, 204);
        assert.equal(element.b, 136);
      });
    });
  });
}());
```

The `setTimeout` depending on the milliseconds specified fails occasionally. I used the [Unit Testing Polymer Elements](https://gist.github.com/addyosmani/b318ca7618eed38c05e1) guide to determine the `Platform.flush` and the `setTimeout` but it seems unreliable for testing.

Is there a reliable way I can make sure the `then` function is ran after the Polymer attribute changes have propagated?

Comment: I've the same problem. Do you have any news on that?

Comment: @silentHoo, nope no word